# Paypal IPN using PHP to get customized Quantity and Amount

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have downloaded the sample paypal IPN script using php and customised with the email for the buyout option and it has also some hidden paramaters such as amount, quantity,return_url, notify_url like this. My main idea is to do the buyout option for the product purchase in my website.The current calculation for the product purchase is as follows:

```
      Item Price:$20
      Quantity  :10
                           Total amount $200
```

I need the calculation to some different way as our site have some static set of quantities and prices, so our point of calculation is as follows:

```
       Item Price:$20
       Quantity  :10    

                           Total amount:$20
```

So, the total amount needs to be the same for the given number of quantities.The IPN configuration doesn't allow me to change the quantity field by this way, please suggest some ideas to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The item price is price per item, the quantity is of course multiplied by the item price.  Your second example should have $2 as the --Item-- price.  If you want to sell "10 items for $20", I think you will need to make a new item for that combo and just but the actual quantity in a custom field.

If you want to use the same item and paypal's quantity field, I think you need to look into calculating a discount and making that part of the parameters (discount_amount_cart or discount_amount_X for item X I think).

Comment: Is there any code sample to add custom quantity field.i have different set of Quantities and its corresponding prices. so please let me know is it possible to use that custom field for all those quantities

Comment: thanks for your ideas. The problem is if we do so , then that Discount parameter will show in the paypal part i was not allowed to show that, so this will not fix this problem i hope.